# SQL : Multiple String Replace (Add a space in front of capital letter(s) starting with 2nd capital letter)

Tags: mysql, sql

I've updated the `Name_Table.column_2` data with wrong strings. Instead of 'John Smith',I've updated with `'JohnSmith'`.

Now i would like to replace multiple strings,For Example : `'JohnSmith'` as `'John Smith'` , `'JohnDoe'` as `'John Doe'` etc.

I'm not familiar with `SQL`, can some one help me on how to replace `multiple strings` all at once.

```
#Name_Table

Column_1      Column_2
1             JohnSmith
2             JohnSmith
3             JohnDoe
4             JohnSmith
5             WayneRooney
6             JohnDoe
7             WayneRooney
8             JohnSmith
9             WayneRooney
10            JohnDoe
```

Comment: what is the field name?

Comment: is firstname and lanstname first letter always capitalised?

Comment: @IgorVujovic : Yes , It will be always capitalized.

Comment: I have added `(Add a space in front of capital letter(s) starting with 2nd capital letter)` to the question as I think it is what you're trying to do. This might happen very often people updating tables and forgetting the space ... hopefully your question gets a lot of up votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know single query for this situation, but try below method to solve your problem. I'm sure it works fine for you.

```
$sel = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Name_Table;');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sel)){
    $string = $row['Column_2'];
    $count = strlen($string);
    $strings = array();
    $i = 0;
    $ii = 0;

    while($i < $count)
    {
        $char = $string{$i};
        if(ereg("[A-Z]", $char, $val)){
            $ii++;
            $s = '';
            $s .= $char;
        } else {
            $s .= $char;
        }
        $strings[$ii] = $s;
        $i++;
    }
    $name_with_space = implode(' ',$strings);
    mysql_query('UPDATE Name_Table SET Column_2="'.$name_with_space.'" WHERE Column_1='.$row['Column_1']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if your names are always gonna be in the format of FirstnameLastname
you can do a custom function like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION breakup_name (fullname varchar(50))
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
BEGIN
  SET @fullname = fullname,@newname='',@letter='',@capcount=0,@space='';
  WHILE LENGTH(@fullname)>0 DO
    SET @letter = LEFT(@fullname,1);
    SET @space = '';
    IF @letter RLIKE BINARY '[A-Z]' THEN
      SET @capcount = @capcount+1;
      IF @capcount >= 2 THEN SET @space = ' '; END IF;
    END IF;
    SET @newname = CONCAT(@newname,@space,@letter);
    SET @fullname = RIGHT(@fullname,LENGTH(@fullname)-1);
  END WHILE;
  RETURN @newname;
END/
```

then use an UPDATE like this.

```
UPDATE table1 SET column_2 = breakup_name(column_2);
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f235a/1)

P.S. In the sqlfiddle I used / as delimiter, you'll have to change that according to your delimiter.

The above function will add a space in front of a capital letters (starting with the 2nd capital letter), so for example if you had `TommyJaeSmith`, it'll return `Tommy Jae Smith`.

The logic of this function is very simple, it loops through and looks at each letter.  If the letter is a capital letter it increments a capcount, if the capcount is greater than or equal to 2 (meaning 2nd capital letter or after) it adds a space... to be concatenated in front of the letter.